# Booted up PC for first time in a year and it worked fine, left it running for four hours, then shut it down. Now it power cycles when I turn it on

Tags: windows-7, boot, motherboard, power-supply

My PC was in storage for about a year and last night I booted it up for the first time. It started up and ran fine without any issues and I left it running for about four hours, then turned it off. This morning I turned it on and it's power cycling, turning on for about 1 second, then immediately turning off. I does this about every five seconds.

**Here's what I've tried**

- I've reseated the RAM sticks
- I've tried booting up without the RAM sticks installed
- I've reseated the two power connectors to the motherboard, from the PSU
- I've reseated the CPU fan power connector
- I've reseated the video card
- I've tried booting up without the video card installed
- I've tried disconnecting the HDDs

There are a TON of Google search results for "PC is turning on/off", but they all cover the same two scenarios, 1) the PC is a new build and it's power cycling after booting up for the first time, or 2) The PC is suddenly power cycling after working fine for a long time. I've tried most of the suggestions in those post, except for swapping out the PSU or motherboard, which I'll attempt next, but in the meantime, I was hoping that my specific scenario of having the PC turned off for a year, then having it up boot up successfully and turning it off after letting run for a few hours, THEN experience the power cycling, might lend some additional insight that could help me narrow down the problem further. Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: There's no magic answer.  Start with the easiest -- Try a different, known-good power supply.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, this is a bad capacitor - on the MoBo or in the PSU.

Caps very often have by far the highest load on switchon - so the scenario, where a cap facilitates its own last load cycle is quite common.